# Laravel 5.4 set locale in session

Tags: laravel-5

Update. 
I would like to know how to set locale in session.

my language picker isnt' input type, but just text. here is blade fragment - this is language picker:

```
<div class = "col-lg-5 col-md-5" id = "lang">
    <ul id = "lang_menu">
        <li class = "language active">Latviešu</a></li>
        <li class = "language">Pусский</a></li>
        <li class = "language">English</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here are routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');

Route::get('/mafia', 'PagesController@mafia');

Route::get('/games', 'PagesController@games');

Route::get('/discounts', 'PagesController@discounts');

Route::get('/tournaments', 'PagesController@tournaments');

Route::get('/gallery', 'PagesController@gallery');

Route::get('/aboutus', 'PagesController@aboutus');
```

also i have transladet files who works fine when i changing locale in config

<<----------UPDATED----------------->>

Now i got so far but still its not working. I made this code from one tutorial where all works. I did the same and its not working.

Here is lang choosing Blade :

```
<ul id = "lang_menu">
    <li class = "language active"><a href ="{{ url('/locale/lv') }}">Latviešu</a></li>
    <li class = "language"><a href ="{{ url('/locale/ru') }}">Pусский</a></li>
    <li class = "language"><a href ="{{ url('/locale/en') }}">English</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is routes:

```
Route::get('locale/{locale?}', array('as'=>'set-locale', 'uses'=>'LanguageController@setLocale'));
```

Here is my LanguageController:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;
use URL;

class LanguageController extends Controller
{
public function setLocale($locale='en'){
    if (!in_array($locale, ['en', 'ru', 'lv'])){
        $locale = 'en';
    }
    Session::put('locale', $locale);
    return redirect(url(URL::previous()));
    }
}
```

And here is middleware "Locale":

```
use Closure;
use Session;
use Config;
use App;

class Locale
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
    $locale=Session::get('locale', Config::get('app.locale'));
    App::setLocale($locale);
    return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And added in Kernel.php:

```
    \App\Http\Middleware\Locale::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

Comment: Try to use a middleware. So all your routes implement it. Then with the middleware you will set the locale. For some reason, you have to set the locale for each request that is done.

Comment: You must set `\App\Http\Middleware\Locale::class,` after `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` otherwise the Session is not started...

Answer (score 2):

You can set a route to configure the locale (see [Configuring The Locale](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization#introduction)), and redirect back to the previous url:

```
Route::get('locale/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    $validLocale = in_array($locale, ['lv', 'ru', 'en']);
    if ($validLocale) {
        App::setLocale($locale);
    }
    return back();
});
```

When visitors select locale, get users to your route:

```
<div class = "col-lg-5 col-md-5" id = "lang">
    <ul id = "lang_menu">
        <li class = "language{{ App::isLocale('lv') ? ' active' : '' }}"><a href="/locale/lv">Latviešu</a></li>
        <li class = "language{{ App::isLocale('ru') ? ' active' : '' }}"><a href="/locale/ru">Pусский</a></li>
        <li class = "language{{ App::isLocale('en') ? ' active' : '' }}"><a href="/locale/en">English</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In middleware you must use session obtained from **request**, not from helper session() or Session::get() !

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->session()->has('locale')  ) {
        $locale = $request->session()->get('locale');
        App::setLocale($locale);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Above throws following exception:-
RuntimeException
Session store not set on request.